# Ionic package build unable to build push plugins

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification

I'm trying to build my Ionic2 app with the `ionic package build android` command. The build fails with the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugGoogleServices'.
> File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it.
   Searched Location:
  /home/package/workspace/apps-**********/cordova/platforms/android/src/debug/google-services.json
  /home/package/workspace/apps-**********/cordova/platforms/android/google-services.json
```

The project now uses the cordova-plugin-fcm plugin, and the google-services.json file is in the right place. Tried to solve it by the cordova-google-fcm-config plugin without success.
Before, I tried with the phonegap-plugin-push plugin but that was just simply not included in the build.
The config.xml contains the plugin actually used.

Building on my local machine both builds are correct. How can I use the build service? Where should I copy the google-services.json file?

Answer (score 0):

[From phonegap-plugin-push 2.x documentation -> INSTALLATION](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/INSTALLATION.md):

> As of version 2.0.0 the SENDER_ID parameter has been removed at install time. Instead you put your google-services.json (Android) and/or GoogleService-Info.plist in the root folder of your project and then add the following lines into your config.xml.
>
> In the platform tag for Android add the resource-file tag:
>
> `<platform name="android">
>     <resource-file src="google-services.json" target="google-services.json" />
>   </platform>`

If build command does not work copy the file directly to `platforms/android/google-services.json`